# How to alter commerce checkout form in a custom module?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm using commerce and want to alter the checkout form in a custom module to prepopulate certain fields and hide them.

However, I'm not able to do this using `hook_form_alter()` as well as `hook_commerce_checkout_pane_alter()`.

Here's my sample code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout':
      // Rename the button for example.
      $form['buttons']['continue']['#value'] = t('Overridden value');
      break;
  }
}
```

How can I edit fields that are displayed on checkout?
Is there some other hook I should use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`commerce_checkout_form()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!includes!commerce_checkout.pages.inc/function/commerce_checkout_form/7) (`commerce_checkout_form_checkout` doesn't exist as far as I can tell from greping Commerce's code):

```
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'commerce_checkout_form':
      ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm running into the same issue - the hook works and I can `dpm()` the form, but nothing is altered for real. Will try this now on a clean install and see if I can narrow down the issue. Will post back shortly.

Comment: Oh right...it'll be this then: `MYMODULE_form_alter($form`. Can't alter an external var unless you pass by reference :)

Comment: Yep, that was it - I was missing the `&` in the `$form` argument :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use form_alter to customize commerce checkout page submit button values.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout':
      if (isset($form['buttons']['continue']['#value'])) {
        $form['buttons']['continue']['#value'] = t('Overridden value');
      } 
      break;
  }
}
```