# Customizable product bundles, user can add/remove products

Tags: commerce

I'm looking for ways to implement an e-commerce for an organic farmer who sells their products, he offers products and product bundles. Every product bundles has its own price. Each bundle are predefined products group. But I want that when the user buys, can unchoose at most, two products of the bundle and change them for another product in a predefined group of products.

I wonder if anyone knows how I can work this way the product bundles. I've been searching, I saw Tech Talk about commerce bundles, I tried commerce_bundle... but I can't find anything to do this.

Any idea or clue is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

My solution goes here based on Drupal Commerce-

**Step 1**: Create Product Bundles using Commerce Bundle module. (which you already know).

**Step 2**: Now you have bundles. The next step is your custom functionality to **swap at most two products from the bundle**.

Add a new step to your checkout process to implement the custom functionality refer [Add a new step in Commerce checkout](http://ygerasimov.com/custom-step-in-drupal-commerce-checkout), explore commerce_checkout.api to get the hold on this.

Adding a new step is nothing but adding a new pane (inside a checkout page) in a Drupal Commerce checkout process where you can list the products in the cart and process them using hook_form_alter().
Refer this link for more details [hook_form_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107310/how-to-alter-commerce-checkout-form-in-a-custom-module).

You can make use of hooks provided by Drupal Commerce such as commerce_cart.api, commerce_order.api to edit/update the cart.

**Step 3**: After processing the cart contents you can update the order details/status using commerce_order.api.

You can alter the checkout pane settings from **Home » Administration » Store » Configuration » Checkout Settings** page.

**Note**: You must have Drupal 7 module development knowledge to implement the above solution.

I hope this helps! Thank You.